# Error: Invalid <Link> with <a> child after updating to Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js, next.js13

After updating Next.js to version 13, I got this client error

[image]

```
<Link href="/contact">
  <a>
    Contact
  </a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To fix this error, remove the `a` tag from the link. From [the link in the error message](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-new-link-with-extra-anchor):

> Starting with Next.js 13, `<Link>` renders as `<a>`, so attempting to use `<a>` as a child is invalid.

#### Invalid

```
<Link href="/contact">
  <a>Contact</a>
</Link>
```

### Valid

```
<Link href="/contact">
    Contact
</Link>
```

Comment: Given that **the link to the explanation is in the error message** this question and answer do not seem useful.

Comment: Also, when quoting, use blockquote.

Comment: The hard part of this upgrade is tracking down all the instances of this in a sufficiently large codebase. React dev tools isn't a lot of help either. Took me hours to kill all the warnings.

Comment: @serraosays - What I did was to find all '<Link' using VS Code searh with case sensitive on. 

If you don't like that method, you can change the behavior of Link from next.config, though I prefer this new method

Comment: Yeah I prefer the newer approach as well.

Answer (score 5):

In Next.13, you don't need to wrap  with . But if you need it, you need to add legacyBehavior props to the `<Link>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are migrating to Next 13 and you have used `<Link>` tag at so many places. You could deactivate the behaviour through next.config.js though.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    newNextLinkBehavior: false,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Thanks to icyJoseph: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/42994#discussioncomment-4181081

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but don’t you like the new behavior instead of having to put a tag everywhere

Answer (score 2):

Starting with **Next.js 13**, `<Link>` renders as `<a>`, so attempting to use `<a>` as a child is invalid.

Run the `new-link` codemod to automatically upgrade previous versions of Next.js to the new  usage:

```
npx @next/codemod new-link .
```

This will change <`Link><a id="link">Home<a></Link>` to `<Link id="link">Home</Link>`.

Alternatively, you can add the `legacyBehavior` prop `<Link legacyBehavior><a id="link">Home</a></Link>`.

ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-new-link-with-extra-anchor

Answer (score 1):

This means in your code, you have `<a>` inside `<link>` tags, you can simply remove `<a>` and make sure the attributes moved to `<link>`tags.

so one of the best practice for Productions is to lock down the NextJs version in case Breaking changes like this happen without awareness.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to wrap each other it's not a good behavior but if you need it, you can add 'legacyBehavior' in Link. it will work. like this -

```
<Link legacyBehavior href={"/fashion"}>
            <a className="text-decoration-none">
              <div></div>
            </a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Placing div inside an a tag is not really good for SEO

Comment: yeh! That's why I mentioned that it's not a good behavior

Answer (score -1):

To fix this error simply replace your code with the given below code.

```
<Link href="/contact">Contact</Link>
```

I hope so it will work

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74530783/2227743).